# Using Powershell to locate and update key value in a text file

Tags: powershell

I have a text file (test.txt) containing the below:

```
User : MikeyMouse
Pswd : mycrazypswd
connectionstring : serverepor:80,pass=809hjhlkusfasdf,somepropert=somevalue
```

I need to use PS to update the above file's key value to mask passwords as shown below with "---"

```
sser : MikeyMouse
pswd : my---wd
connectionstring : serverepor:80,pass=80---df,somepropert=somevalue
```

Any suggestions on how bet to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Get/Set-Content` and a Regex `-Replace` will do the trick.

```
$Path = 'test.txt'
$NewContent = (Get-Content -Path $Path -Raw) -replace '(?<=Pswd : ..)(.*)(?=..\r)', '---' -replace '(?<=pass=..)(.*?)(?=..,)', '---' 
Set-Content -Path $Path -Value $NewContent
```

References:

[.Net Regex cheat sheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

Special thanks

@olaf: For showing me the lookahead/lookbehind way.

Comment: Hi Sage... you are a life saver.  This works for most part.  For the "pass=" replace, your code return only "pass=80---" instead of "pass=80---df".

Comment: @UltraGC Indeed. I fixed my answer.